# Websphere MQ - WCF - Common cause of AMQ9504: A protocol

Tags: c#, wcf, ibm-mq

We are sporadically experiencing an error that is causing issues for one of our WCF / Websphere MQ applications.  We are encountering the error:

Websphere MQ Server: 7.1
Websphere MQ Client: 7.1
.Net 4.0

----- amqrmrsa.c : 887 --------------------------------------------------------
1/23/2013 06:13:26 - Process(2928.79887) User(svcPrideDaca) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(MQTEST) Installation(MQServer7101)
                      VRMF(7.1.0.0) QMgr(QM_mqtest)

```
AMQ9504: A protocol error was detected for channel 'SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN'.

EXPLANATION:
During communications with the remote queue manager, the channel program
detected a protocol error. The failure type was 11 with associated data of 252.
ACTION:
Contact the systems administrator who should examine the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure.
```

Error we are getting in our WCF .Net App:

```
2013-01-23 06:13:25,435 [113] ERROR - [pride-N25Scan].[EnqueueMessage] <54321> (9999) Error enquing message:WCFCH0309E: An error occurred while attempting to open the channel for endpoint 'jms:/queue?destination=Q_Daca_JMS@QM_mqtest&connectionFactory=binding(client)connectQueueManager(QM_mqtest)clientConnection(test.mq.com(1415))clientChannel(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN)&initialContextFactory=com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi'
The operation could not be completed.
The endpoint may be down, unavailable, or unreachable, review the linked exception for further details.
    Server stack trace: 
       at IBM.XMS.WCF.ExceptionHelper.ThrowCommsException(OperationType op, Exception innerException, String endpointURI)
       at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsOutputChannel.OnEndOpen(IAsyncResult result)
       at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsOutputChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at IMessage.ProcessMqMessage(String msg)
       at N25Scan.EnqueueMessage(String message)
```

We cannot isolate what is causing the issue.  We have tried to make modifications to the application to re-establish connections when this issue is encountered, but are still trying to figure out the cause.

When the app encounters this error all of the connections start failing / timing out so we had to ensure that all of the connections success or fail are properly disposing the WCF / Websphere MQ connections.

Any tips / info would be greatly appreciated.  Cannot find anything help thus far searching the web.

Thanks,

S

Comment: Was there no additional information in the error logs?

Comment: Just had a chat with a colleague ... 252 is a magic number with MQ apparently - any chance you've got more than 252 threads/apps/users on that channel. Might explain why it's sporadic

Comment: I was looking in the error log under the queue manager to acquire the message I embedded above...I didn't see anything under the system log, nor did I see anything in the client logs.  There is a good chance I am looking in the wrong location...Should I be looking somewhere other than the logs under the queue manager?  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Ahhh THat could be the problem.....we were possibly not properly closing the threads which was causing the massive amount of traffic on that channel...Thanks CHill60 I will look into that greatly appreciate the advice!

Comment: Let me know how you get on ... also if you have access to IBM Redbooks you might find "Problem Determination Across Multiple WebSphere Products" has some other ideas - it's a bit old (2004) but sometimes the age old problems catch us out again and again :-)